Slider photo gallery React Slick
I'm using React Slick to create a slider with custom arrows and pagination as pictures to create a gallery, I have created the custom arrows perfectly and positioned them in the position I want them which is inside the image , but now I'm not able to postion the pagination where I want and also when I increase the size if the pagination they get overlapped, can someone who worked before with React Slick can show me how it can be done :
This is what I'm trying to achieve :

This is the slider I have made, I have managed to do the first part which is the arrows but the pagination being images and justified to left , not able to do it :
"use client";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import React, { Component, useRef } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

function ProductDetailsSlider() {
  let sliderRef = useRef(null);
  const next = () => {
//@ts-ignore
sliderRef.slickNext();
  };
  const previous = () => {
//@ts-ignore
sliderRef.slickPrev();
  };
  const settings = {
customPaging: function (i: any) {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full bg-yellow-500">
      <div className="w-full h-full bg-purple-500">
        <img
          src={`/assets/images/abstract0${i + 1}.jpg`}
          className="w-full h-full object-cover"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
},
dots: true,
dotsClass: "slick-dots slick-thumb",
infinite: false,
speed: 500,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
arrows: false,
  };
  return (
<div className="relative w-[483px] h-[470px]">
  <Slider
    ref={(slider) => {
      //@ts-ignore
      sliderRef = slider;
    }}
    {...settings}
    className="w-full h-full rounded-[20px] border-[1px] border-primary-300 relative"
  >
    <div className="bg-yellow-500 w-[483px] h-[470px] rounded-[20px] overflow-hidden">
      {/* <div className="w-full h-full bg-purple-500 overflow-hidde rounded-[20px]"> 
     */}
      <img
        src={`/assets/images/abstract01.jpg`}
        className="object-cover w-full h-full"
      />
      {/* </div> */}
    </div>

    <div className="bg-yellow-500 w-[483px] h-[470px] rounded-[20px] overflow-hidden">
      <img
        src={`/assets/images/abstract02.jpg`}
        className="object-cover w-full h-full"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="bg-yellow-500 w-[483px] h-[470px] rounded-[20px] overflow-hidden">
      <img
        src={`/assets/images/abstract03.jpg`}
        className="object-cover w-full h-full"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="bg-yellow-500 w-[483px] h-[470px] rounded-[20px] overflow-hidden">
      <img
        src={`/assets/images/abstract04.jpg`}
        className="object-cover w-full h-full"
      />
    </div>
  </Slider>
  <div className="absolute bottom-5 right-5 gap-2 flex">
    <button className="button" onClick={previous}>
      <img src="/assets/icons/circle-arrow.svg" className="rotate-180" />
    </button>
    <button className="button" onClick={next}>
      <img src="/assets/icons/circle-arrow.svg" />
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetailsSlider;

